# Best practices for using multiple generic views and a form within one class based view in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, multiple-inheritance, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I'm trying to figure out how to use multiple class based generic views with forms in Django 1.7. I am familiar with function based views but have only recently been trying class based views.

The way that I understand what I class based view is that it is a python class that contains the methods, among others, post, get, delete, and the other HTTP request methods. These methods are called when one of the request methods is recieved. For example if an HTTP GET was received the get() method within the class based view would be executed.

Now on the Django [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) they give this block of code as an example for their views.py file

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']

class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']

class AuthorDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Author
    success_url = reverse_lazy('author-list')
```

I am a bit confused by this though because I would think it would be better to do something like this instead:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from myapp.models import Author

class Author(CreateView, DeleteView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('author-list')
#I assume this would have to be separate because they both implement a post method
class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
        model = Author
        fields = ['name']
```

because it is fewer lines of code and you would have a single class based view to perform all 3 of these operations. Everything I have been able to find about this online has seemed to mimic the docs and create multiple class based views instead of using multiple generics in one class based view.

My question is, is there a reason that the code is written this way? And what exactly are the best practices for using multiple generics within a single class based view? Or am I even able to use multiple in this way? Essentially would I be allowed to write those three views as I did above?

Comment: Sounds like you are confusing REST and CRUD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question. Those are three separate views, accessed on different URLs, and presumably using different templates. There's nothing to gain by putting them into a single class. On the contrary, it would make things much more complicated: how will you determine if a POST is an update or a delete?

You mention REST at the end. If what you are looking for is some kind of REST API, then you really need [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), which provides generic REST-based views.